# How to get the complete row from a maximum calculation?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by

I do struggle with a `GROUP BY` -- again. The basics I can handle, but there it is: How do I get to different columns I named in the `group by`, without destroying my grouping? Note that `group by` is only my own idea, there may be others that work better. It must work in Oracle, though.

Here is my example:

```
create table xxgroups (
  groupid int not null primary key,
  groupname varchar2(10)
);
insert into xxgroups values(100, 'Group 100');
insert into xxgroups values(200, 'Group 200');

drop table xxdata;
create table xxdata (
  num1 int,
  num2 int,
  state_a int,
  state_b int,
  groupid int,
    foreign key (groupid) references xxgroups(groupid)
);
-- "ranks" are 90, 40, null, 70:
insert into xxdata values(10, 10, 1, 4, 100);
insert into xxdata values(10, 10, 0, 4, 200);
insert into xxdata values(11, 11, 0, 3, 100);
insert into xxdata values(20, 22, 5, 7, 200);
```

The task is to create a result-row for each `distinct (num1, num2)` and print that `groupname` with the highest calculated "rank" from `state_a` and `state_b`.

> Note that the first two rows have the same `num`s and thus only the higher ranking should be selected -- with the `groupname` being "Group 200".

I got quite far with the basic `group by`, I think.

```
SELECT xd.num1||xd.num2 nummer, max(ranking.goodness)
FROM xxdata xd
    , xxgroups xg
    ,( select state_a, state_b, r as goodness
       from dual
       model return updated rows
       dimension by (0 state_a, 0 state_b) measures (0 r)
       rules (r[1,4]=90, r[3,7]=80,r[5,7]=70, r[4,7]=60, r[0,7]=50, r[0,4]=40)
       order by goodness desc
      ) ranking
WHERE xd.groupid=xg.groupid
  and ranking.state_a (+) = xd.state_a
  and ranking.state_b (+) = xd.state_b
GROUP BY xd.num1||xd.num2
ORDER BY nummer
;
```

The result is 90% of what I need:

```
nummer   ranking
----------------
1010     90
1111      
2022     70
```

100% perfect would be

```
nummer   groupname
-------------------
1010     Group 100
1111     Group 100
2022     Group 200
```

- The tricky part is, that I want the `groupname` in the result. And I can not include it in the `select`, because then I would *have* to put it into the `group by` as well -- which I do *not* want (then I would not select the best ranking entry from over all groups)
- In my solution a use a `model` table to calculate the "rank". There are other solution I am sure. The point is, that it is a non-trivial calculation that I do not want to do twice.
- I know from other examples that one could use a second query to get back to the original row to get to the `groupname`, but I can not see how I could to this here, 
  without duplicating my ranking calculation.
- A nice suggestion was to replace the `group by` with a `LIMIT 1`/`ORDER BY goodness` and use this calculating select as a filtering subselect. But a) there is no `LIMIT` in Oracle, and I doubt a `rownum<=1` would do in a subselect and b) I can not wrap my brain around it anyway. Maybe there is a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`FIRST`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions065.htm#i1000901) aggregation modifier to selectively apply your function over a subset of rows of a group -- here a single row ([SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fd0f8/14)):

```
SELECT xd.num1||xd.num2 nummer, 
       MAX(xg.groupname) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST 
                               ORDER BY ranking.goodness DESC) grp,
       max(ranking.goodness)
FROM xxdata xd
    , xxgroups xg
    ,( select state_a, state_b, r as goodness
       from dual
       model return updated rows
       dimension by (0 state_a, 0 state_b) measures (0 r)
       rules (r[1,4]=90, r[3,7]=80,r[5,7]=70, r[4,7]=60, r[0,7]=50, r[0,4]=40)
       order by goodness desc
      ) ranking
WHERE xd.groupid=xg.groupid
  and ranking.state_a (+) = xd.state_a
  and ranking.state_b (+) = xd.state_b
GROUP BY xd.num1||xd.num2
ORDER BY nummer;
```

Your method with analytics works as well but since we already use aggregations here, we may as well use the `FIRST` modifier to get all columns in one go.

Comment: Interesting. I will look up the documentation of `KEEP` and `FIRST`. Is my guess correct that in essence you apply a `max()` were where the calculating operation is done on a different column? I.e. the `max(xg.groupname)` itself would not make sense, thus you tell Oracle to calculate that maximum "please refer to a dense_ranking, using the first result when you order by goodness descending-wise"? This sounds like a general solution to the "I-want-to-get-to-the-other-columns-of-the-group-by"-problem, right?

Comment: Yes, it lets Oracle apply the `MAX(groupname)` function only on the rows that have maximum `goodness`. In essence if `goodness` is unique, it lets you select any column of the row that has the maximum value of another column.

Comment: Great. With [this docu](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions.php) I do understand the `FIRST` easily. Doesn't that suggest I could replace the `group by` with an `over (partition by ...)`, too?

Comment: ...oh, do I have to add a `distinct ...` in the outermost select, because with `dense_rank` could return multiple rows with rank=1? Or does `dense_rank first` guarantee that only one row is returned?

Comment: I better keep my `distinct`, as you can see on [Sql-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4403e/3), for if I have complete duplicates in my input data, to get rid of those.

Comment: Why did remove the GROUP BY? You've mixed both methods (analytics **and** `KEEP FIRST`). I suggest you pick one for now and don't try to mix them :) Either go with analytics (using `OVER`, your solution) or `KEEP FIRST ... GROUP BY`.

Comment: Uh, ok I thought by getting rid of `group by` I would get rid of a concept. I guess I have no clear distinction in my head what is "analytical" and what isn't. So, `KEEP FIRST` and `GROUP BY` belong to one family. Ok.

Comment: All [aggregate functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions003.htm#i89203) belong to one family. They are either used with `GROUP BY` *or* `OVER` (in that case they become [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#i81407)). You can further modify an aggregate function by adding `KEEP FIRST`. Simple, isn't it ? :) Right now in your case I wouldn't recommend using **BOTH** `OVER` and `KEEP FIRST`.

Answer (score 2):

Whow, I did search before, but now I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10670844/472245), which I could adopt to my question. The Oracle-solution here is `over`, `partition by` with `order by` and `row_number()`:

```
select *
from ( select data.*, row_number()
         over (partition by nummer order by goodness desc) as seqnum
from (
SELECT xd.num1, xd.num2 nummer, xg.groupname, ranking.goodness
FROM xxdata xd
    , xxgroups xg
    ,( select state_a, state_b, r as goodness
       from dual
       model return updated rows
       dimension by (0 state_a, 0 state_b) measures (0 r)
       rules (r[1,4]=90, r[3,7]=80,r[5,7]=70, r[4,7]=60, r[0,7]=50, r[0,4]=40)
      ) ranking
WHERE xd.groupid=xg.groupid
  and ranking.state_a (+) = xd.state_a
  and ranking.state_b (+) = xd.state_b
ORDER BY nummer
) data )
where seqnum = 1
;
```

The result is

```
    10         10 Group 100          90          1
    11         11 Group 100                      1
    20         22 Group 200          70          1
```

which is beautiful.

Now I have to try to understand what `over` in the `select` excactly does....